# HtmlAgilityPack - how to grab <DIV> data in a large web page

Tags: c#, web-applications, html-agility-pack, html-generation

I am trying  to grab  a data from a WEBPAGE ,  `<DIV>`particular class  `<DIV class="personal_info">`  it has 10   similar `<DIV>`S and is of same Class "Personal_info" ( as shown in HTML  Code   and now i want to extract all the DIVs of Class personal_info which are in  10 - 15 in every webpage .

`<div class="personal_info"><span class="bold">Rama Anand</span><br><br> Mobile: 9916184586<br>rama_asset@hotmail.com<br> Bangalore</div>`

to do the needful i started using HTML AGILE PACK as suggested by some one in Stack overflow 
and  i stuck at the beginning it self bcoz of lack of knowledge in HtmlAgilePack  my C# code goes like this

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument docHtml = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb docHFile = new HtmlWeb();

        docHtml = docHFile.Load("http://127.0.0.1/2.html");
```

then how to  code further   so that data from  DIV whose class is "personal_info" can be grabbed ...  suggestion with example will be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I can't check this right now, but isn't it:

```
var infos = from info in docHtml.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='personal_info']") select info;
```

Answer (score 2):

To get a url loaded you can do something like:

```
 var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument(); 
 var url = "http://www.google.com";
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
 using (var responseStream =  request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
 {
   document.Load(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
 }
```

Also note there is a fork to let you use jquery selectors in agility pack.

```
IEnumerable<HtmlNode> myList = document.QuerySelectorAll(".personal_info");
```

http://yosi-havia.blogspot.com/2010/10/using-jquery-selectors-on-server-sidec.html

Comment: +1 I didn't know there was a server side jQuery selector available, awesome. I traditionally used xpath with HtmlAgilityPack

Answer (score 0):

What happened to Where?

```
node.DescendantNodes().Where(node_it => node_it.Name=="div");
```

if you want top node (root) you use page.DocumentNode as "node".